# Specify location of Maven Descriptor

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am using *Maven 3.2.1* to build my archives (JARs, WARs and EARs). Maven puts its descriptor files (`pom.xml`and `pom.properties`) in `META-INF/maven/${groupId}/{artifactId}`.

Is it possible to change the location in a way that these two files will be places directly in `META-INF`with no sub folders?

Maybe I could use the resources plugin to place them there directly. But where do I get the `pom.propereties`from then?

Additionally I did not manage to get the resources plugin configured for EARs and WARs. Adding a `resources`section to the `build`section of an EAR or WAR seems to have no effect.

Comment: are you know the content of pom.properties file?

=====may be like below===========
#Generated by Maven
#Mon May 19 10:54:52 CST 2014
version=0.2.0
groupId=****
artifactId=***

Comment: And why would you want to do this? This is the way Maven works.

Comment: At the startup of our application we want to read information out of it, mainly for logging/monitoring purpose. We are migrating from Maven 1 to Maven 3 and in the past we had the "project.xml" directly in META-INF and could read all "project.xml"s using `Enumeration<URL> e = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/project.xml");`. Reading from unknown folders is more difficult. A solution could be to write the relevant information (artifact name and version) into MANIFEST instead.

Comment: information/configuration for logging and monitoring is not part of the Maven files, which first of all contain build-information and the runtime dependencies. Please create your own .properties files for configuration of logging and monitoring.

Comment: I do not want to use the pom.xml/pom.properties to configure the logging, I just want to print out the artifact Ids and versions of all the JARs that are part of my `war` file.

Comment: Is this information just for information purposes or do you need something else?

Comment: We want to read artifact Id and version number of each JAR and store it in a map. We have a configuration framework in place where config settings can be made based on the deployed artifact and version. So at runtime we need to know the versions of the artifacts being deployed.